# React not recognizing onScroll event

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to trigger an onScroll event in React that is not working. I have:

```
useEffect(() => {
        //const myNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(refs.PeopleHolderRef)
        //myNode.addEventListener('scroll', handlePeopleScroll);
        //if(PeopleHolderRef.current){
            PeopleHolderRef.current.addEventListener('scroll', handlePeopleScroll);
        //}
}
```

```
const reactionItems = <div onScroll = {handlePeopleScroll}>{people && [...Object.values(people)] //makes mappable
                                    //.sort((a, b) => a.time - b.time)
                                    .map((onePerson, index) => (
                                        <>
                                            <OnePeopleDivPerson onePerson = {onePerson} />
                                            
                                            
                                       
                                        </>
                                    ))  }</div>
```

```
const handlePeopleScroll = async(e) => {
    console.log("got into handlePeopleScroll")
    const currentScrollY = e.target.scrollBottom;
    if(currentScrollY == 0){
    //if(window.pageYOffset === 0) {
        console.log("got into handlePeopleScroll at bottom")
        renewMyPeople();
    }
}
```

It never says that I got into handlePeopleScroll. I've tried all the things on the internet and have put the onScroll attribute into many different containing divs in different places. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to this example.

https://codepen.io/JohnReynolds57/pen/NLNOyO?editors=0011

```
class ScrollAwareDiv extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.myRef = React.createRef()
    this.state = {scrollTop: 0}
  }
  
  onScroll = () => {
    const scrollY = window.scrollY //Don't get confused by what's scrolling - It's not the window
    const scrollTop = this.myRef.current.scrollTop
    console.log(`onScroll, window.scrollY: ${scrollY} myRef.scrollTop: ${scrollTop}`)
    this.setState({
      scrollTop: scrollTop
    })
  }

  render() {
    const {
      scrollTop
    } = this.state
    return (
      <div
        ref={this.myRef}
        onScroll={this.onScroll}
        style={{
          border: '1px solid black',
          width: '600px',
          height: '100px',
          overflow: 'scroll',
        }} >
        <p>This demonstrates how to get the scrollTop position within a scrollable react component.</p>
        <p>ScrollTop is {scrollTop}</p>
        <p>This demonstrates how to get the scrollTop position within a scrollable react component.</p>
        <p>ScrollTop is {scrollTop}</p>
        <p>This demonstrates how to get the scrollTop position within a scrollable react component.</p>
        <p>ScrollTop is {scrollTop}</p>
        <p>This demonstrates how to get the scrollTop position within a scrollable react component.</p>
        <p>ScrollTop is {scrollTop}</p>
        <p>This demonstrates how to get the scrollTop position within a scrollable react component.</p>
        <p>ScrollTop is {scrollTop}</p>
        <p>This demonstrates how to get the scrollTop position within a scrollable react component.</p>
        <p>ScrollTop is {scrollTop}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ScrollAwareDiv />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Hook version:

```
import React, {useRef, useState} from 'react';

const ScrollAwareDiv  = () => {
  const myRef = useRef();
  const [scrollTop, setScrollTop] = useState(0);

  const onScroll = () => {
    const scrollY = window.scrollY //Don't get confused by what's scrolling - It's not the window
    const scrollTop = myRef.current.scrollTop;
    console.log(`onScroll, window.scrollY: ${scrollY} myRef.scrollTop: ${scrollTop}`)
    setScrollTop(scrollTop);
  }
  return (
    (
      <div
        ref={myRef}
        onScroll={onScroll}
        style={{
          border: '1px solid black',
          width: '600px',
          height: '100px',
          overflow: 'scroll',
          color: 'black',
        }} >
        <p>This demonstrates how to get the scrollTop position within a scrollable react component.</p>
        <p>ScrollTop is {scrollTop}</p>
        <p>This demonstrates how to get the scrollTop position within a scrollable react component.</p>
        <p>ScrollTop is {scrollTop}</p>
        <p>This demonstrates how to get the scrollTop position within a scrollable react component.</p>
        <p>ScrollTop is {scrollTop}</p>
        <p>This demonstrates how to get the scrollTop position within a scrollable react component.</p>
        <p>ScrollTop is {scrollTop}</p>
        <p>This demonstrates how to get the scrollTop position within a scrollable react component.</p>
        <p>ScrollTop is {scrollTop}</p>
        <p>This demonstrates how to get the scrollTop position within a scrollable react component.</p>
        <p>ScrollTop is {scrollTop}</p>
      </div>
    )
  )
}
export default ScrollAwareDiv ;
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a solution for hooks? I couldn't get this solution to work with hooks.

Comment: it works for the click event, but when I write scroll instead, it doesn't work.

Comment: @JohnSmith, I added a hook version. Could you test it out again?

Comment: Thanks, I did, and it just never gets into the onScroll function for some reason

Comment: Thanks so much, I tested it on the right div and it worked!